# How can I add a path to the QProcess PATH environment variable? (PyQt5 on Python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, environment-variables, qprocess

#### 1. The problem explained

I instantiate a `QProcess()`-object just before the application shows its main window. The `QProcess()`-instance is stored in the `self.__myProcess` variable, and stays alive as long as you can see the main window.

The main window looks like this:

[image]

When you click on the button, the following code executes:

```
def __btn_clicked(self):
    self.__add_openocd_to_env()
    command = "openocd.exe" + '\r\n'
    self.__myProcess.start(command)
```

The last two lines are quite clear: the command `openocd.exe` is passed to `self.__myProcess` and executes. *What this executable actually does is not important here.* In fact, I could use any random executable. The point is: if the executable is in my Windows `PATH` environment variable, it gets found and executed.

Imagine the executable is NOT in the `PATH` environment variable. Then the function `self.__add_openocd_to_env()` should fix that issue:

```
def __add_openocd_to_env(self):
    env = self.__myProcess.processEnvironment()
    env.insert("PATH", "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0\\bin;" + env.value("PATH"))
    self.__myProcess.setProcessEnvironment(env)
```

However, I've noticed it has no effect at all. I have tried a lot of different things in this function, but it just won't have any effect.

You can find the full code here:
<sub>If you have Python 3 installed with PyQt5, you can simply copy-paste the code into a .py module and run it. You should see the little window with the pushbutton. Of course you should change the path "C:\Users\Kristof.." to something valid on your computer. You can choose any executable you like for this test.</sub>

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # -------------------------------- #
        #          QProcess() setup        #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.__myProcess = QProcess()
        self.__myProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.__myProcess.readyRead.connect(self.__on_output)
        self.__myProcess.errorOccurred.connect(self.__on_error)
        self.__myProcess.finished.connect(self.__on_exit)

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QProcess test")

        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffffff }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)

        self.__myBtn = QPushButton("START QPROCESS()")
        self.__myBtn.clicked.connect(self.__btn_clicked)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedHeight(70)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myBtn)
        self.show()

    def __add_openocd_to_env(self):
        env = self.__myProcess.processEnvironment()
        env.insert("PATH", "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0\\bin;" + env.value("PATH"))
        self.__myProcess.setProcessEnvironment(env)

    def __btn_clicked(self):
        self.__add_openocd_to_env()
        command = "openocd.exe" + '\r\n'
        self.__myProcess.start(command)

    def __on_output(self):
        data = bytes(self.__myProcess.readAll()).decode().replace('\r\n', '\n')
        print(data)

    def __on_error(self, error):
        print("")
        print("Process error: {0}".format(str(error)))
        print("")


    def __on_exit(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        print("")
        print("ExitCode = {0}".format(str(exitCode)))
        print("ExitStatus = {0}".format(str(exitStatus)))
        print("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### 2. My question

I know I could simply add "C:\Users\Kristof\programs\openocd_0.10.0\bin" to my Windows `PATH` environment variable before instantiating the `QProcess()`. But that's not the point. I want to know how to add it to the `PATH` environment variable for that one specific `QProcess()`-instance. If possible, it should not affect any other `QProcess()`-instances around in my software, nor should it affect any future `QProcess()`-instances I create later on.

#### 3. System settings

I use the PyQt5 framework in Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

---

**NOTE:**
I've just tried to improve the `QProcess()` setup in the following way:

```
        # -------------------------------- #
        #          QProcess() setup        #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.__myProcess = QProcess()
        self.__myProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.__myProcess.readyRead.connect(self.__on_output)
        self.__myProcess.errorOccurred.connect(self.__on_error)
        self.__myProcess.finished.connect(self.__on_exit)

        # NEW: initialize the environment variables for self.__myProcess:
        env = QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
        self.__myProcess.setProcessEnvironment(env)
```

I was hopefull ... but it still won't work :-(

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding.  You are trying to affect the `PATH` environment which gets passed to the sub-process.  What you *want* to do is simply alter the `PATH` environment in the *parent*, it is that which needs to find your executable before the sub-process can get spawned.  And if you want to, then change your parent's `PATH` back *after* the sub-process has been spawned.

Comment: Hi @JonBrave, you have a point there. Could you perhaps illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment of Mr. @JonBrave, I have written the following workaround:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()
        # -------------------------------- #
        #          QProcess() setup        #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.__myProcess = QProcess()
        self.__myProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.__myProcess.readyRead.connect(self.__on_output)
        self.__myProcess.errorOccurred.connect(self.__on_error)
        self.__myProcess.finished.connect(self.__on_exit)

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QProcess test")

        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffffff }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)

        self.__myBtn = QPushButton("START QPROCESS()")
        self.__myBtn.clicked.connect(self.__btn_clicked)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedHeight(70)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myBtn)
        self.show()

    def __add_openocd_to_env(self):
        self.__oldEnv = os.environ["PATH"]
        os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\Dropbox (Personal)\\EMBEDOFFICE\\embedoffice\\resources\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0_dev00459\\bin;" + self.__oldEnv

    def __remove_openocd_from_env(self):
        os.environ["PATH"] = self.__oldEnv

    def __btn_clicked(self):
        self.__add_openocd_to_env()
        command = "openocd.exe" + '\r\n'
        self.__myProcess.start(command)
        self.__myProcess.waitForStarted(-1)
        self.__remove_openocd_from_env()

    def __on_output(self):
        data = bytes(self.__myProcess.readAll()).decode().replace('\r\n', '\n')
        print(data)

    def __on_error(self, error):
        print("")
        print("Process error: {0}".format(str(error)))
        print("")

    def __on_exit(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        print("")
        print("ExitCode = {0}".format(str(exitCode)))
        print("ExitStatus = {0}".format(str(exitStatus)))
        print("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Basically I'm doing the following: just before ordering the `QProcess()`-instance to start a command, I add the executable path to the `PATH` environment variable that belongs to the whole Python session. Once the command has started, I can remove it again so it won't have an effect on other `QProcess()`-instances created in the future.

It works, but it will certainly require a lot of "bookkeeping" if I'm going to apply that approach in my software (many `QProcess()`-instances live in my software). If you find a better approach, please don't hesitate to share!

Comment: Looks good.  Sorry, I don't have time to type an answer!  You could *probably* call `__remove_openocd_from_env()` straight after `start()`, before `waitForStarted()` (which you then wouldn't need) to reduce changed-environment-exposure time (try it?).  You could derive your own class from `QProcess` to use just for this case to avoid changing the others.  Finally, you could do this from a `.bat` file on your `PATH`/in your current directory which changes PATH before invoking `openocd.exe`, then it's in one place (and you can change the path) and you don't have to alter `QProcess`... :)

Comment: Just noticed your code's: `command = "openocd.exe" + '\r\n'`.  Take out that CRLF stuff, it's got no place in issuing an OS command.

Comment: And finally, from the example you give, if you *know* that the `exe` is located in the directory you're adding to `PATH`, and the exe itself does not need the PATH to be changed for its own purposes, just make the full path to the exe yourself and invoke it that way, *much* simpler.

Comment: this process worked for me on linux. useful since I plan on making my own IDE. thanks for the question and answer.

Comment: Hi @SpencerWilliams, what kind of IDE are you planning to make?

Comment: @K.Muller sorry for the late delay. to be honest, I didn't expect a response. Basically something similar to vs code. I will have to implement advanced features, which is why I am also integrating cython to make it not use all the resources. I love both languages, and figured it would be easier this way. but to justify it, I would have to implement features to where others can include plugins. I plan to keep the plugin API in python and PyQt5. I am thinking of having cython handle the real intrusive processes. Use c to maybe do extra management backend.

Comment: Hi @SpencerWilliams, that's interesting. I'm working in a startup team. We're building a new IDE for microcontrollers: https://embeetle.com

Comment: @K.Muller that is awesome. I want to make it flexible like vs code so that way It can handle everything. from python, to c++, web, godot, unreal engine, blender, microcontrollers etc. I want it to be a good alternative to vs code just in case.

Comment: You have a website @SpencerWilliams?

Comment: @K.Mulier https://anutechtr.com is my business website. sorry been busy. business is stable so far.

Comment: Very interesting @SpencerWilliams, please add me on LinkedIn. My name is: Kristof Mulier

Comment: @K.Mulier okay sure, but I should warn you, I am red pilled so naturally my lack of klaxks to give has caused me to be shunned in liberal society, and ultimately banned everywhere most people congregate, so I am already banned on facebook, google, twitter, reddit, pinterest, all the networks guilty of censorship, racism, and their active war against people who stand up to them. I am one of them, so I will likely be banned on linkedin before too long. I use my skills to fight the liberal bigoted society, as a result, I am actively a threat to google and facebook.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using python subprocess.run() instead of QProcess.

In subprocess.run(),  you can specify a set of environment variables (actually a dictionary) using the `env` parameter. The idea is to take a copy of your original environment,  modify the PATH variable, and pass the modified environment to subprocess.run, as follows:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0\\bin" \
   + os.pathsep + env['PATH']
subprocess.run("openocd", env=env)
```

This still doesn't work: the remaining problem is that the environment (including the modified PATH variable) will be available in the subprocess but is not used to search for the openocd command.  But that is easy to fix: subprocess.run also has a boolean `shell` parameter (default False) that tells it to run the command in a shell. Since the shell will run in the subprocess, it will use the modified PATH to search for openocd.  So working code is:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0\\bin" \
   + os.pathsep + env['PATH']
subprocess.run("openocd", env=env, shell=True)
```

An alternative for shell=True is to use shutil.which (available in Python >= 3.3) to resolve the command.  This will also work reliably when the command is given as a list of strings instead of a single string.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = "C:\\Users\\Kristof\\programs\\openocd_0.10.0\\bin" \
   + os.pathsep + env['PATH']
command = shutil.which("openocd", path = self.env.get('PATH', None))
subprocess.run([ command ], env=env)
```